# About argument and modulus of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Let $ϕ(s)$ be an analytic function that has zeros outside a **simply connected domain** $D$. The function $ϕ(s)$ can be written as $ϕ(s)=ϕ₁(s)+iϕ₂(s)$ and therefore it is given uniquely by the polar form $ϕ(s)=ρ(s)exp(iθ(s))$, where, $ρ(s)=√(ϕ₁²(s)+ϕ₂²(s))≠0$ is the magnitude and $θ(s)=argϕ(s)∈ℝ$, is the argument of $ϕ(s)$.

We know that:

**(P)**: If $ϕ(s)≠0$ and $ϕ$ is entire, then $θ(s)$ and $ρ(s)$ can be well-defined without **branch cuts** (the main reason here is that poles and zeros require branch cuts).

My **question** is: Does the property (P) holds true (at least locally) if we replace $ℂ$ by the simply connected domain $D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Starting with some $z_0\in D$, pick a value for $\log \phi(z_0)$ and proceed to define   $\log \phi$ in $D$ by analytic continuation. The monodromy theorem tells you that $\log \phi$ is single-valued, no branch cuts. The real and imaginary parts of $\log \phi$ give what you want.

Comment: @ user98130: But you do not uese the fact that $D$ is simply connected domain.

Comment: @AR1 The [monodromy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy_theorem), as stated at the end of the article, requires the domain to be simply connected.

Comment: @ user98130: Thank you very much.